# How parse a comment with custom markup to html markup using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, regex, regexp-replace

Hay,

I'm trying to achieve the below using regex but it looks too complex.

Input: `Hello, @[John Doe](600f2e41-0e31-4864-cb18-f8b255788f1c) please confirm with @[Rose Marie](600f2e41-0e33-6864-ab86-f8b255788f1c)`

Output: `Hello, <span>@John Doe</span> please confirm with <span>@Rose Marie</span>`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [`/@\[(?<name>[^\]]+)\]\([^)]+\)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/prbQzl/1)

Comment: Post the answer :). Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
const comment = 'Hello, @[John Doe](600f2e41-0e31-4864-cb18-f8b255788f1c) please confirm with @[Rose Marie](600f2e41-0e33-6864-ab86-f8b255788f1c)';

const regex = /@\[(.*?)\]\(.*?\)/g;
return comment.replaceAll(regex, '<span>@$1</span>');
```